# How to pick records from sqlite3 by date through a user defined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a model named GuestOrder:

```
class GuestOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: guest_orders
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  notes          :string(255)
#  adults         :integer
#  children       :integer
#  created        :datetime
#  placed         :datetime
#  billed         :datetime
#  user_id        :integer
#  guest_table_id :integer
#  take_away_id   :integer
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
```

And a controller

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def getOrdersByDate
    @guest_orders = GuestOrder.where(:created_at => (params[:created]))
    render json: @guest_orders
  end
end
```

In `routes.rb`

```
  match '/api/getOrdersByDate'
```

When I try to get this in url

```
http://localhost:3000/api/getOrdersByDate?:created=2012-4-5
```

I got all the records not restricted by date

In server I got `select * from guest_orders`

```
Started GET "/api/getOrdersByDate?:created=2012-4-5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-06 13:19:59 +0530
  Processing by ApiController#getOrdersByDate as HTML
  Parameters: {":created"=>"2012-4-5"}
  GuestOrder Load (26.3ms)  SELECT "guest_orders".* FROM "guest_orders"
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 26.3ms)


Started GET "/api/getOrdersByDate?:created=2012-4-5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-06 13:21:21 +0530
  Processing by ApiController#getOrdersByDate as HTML
  Parameters: {":created"=>"2012-4-5"}
  GuestOrder Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "guest_orders".* FROM "guest_orders"
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Records in my DB have records in date `2012-03-22, 2012-04-05, 2012-04-06`

How can I query in `getOrdersByDate` to get records of a particular date.

Comment: Are you using `development` environment? If not you may need to reload your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the colon in your request, [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) wiill do the sym lookup for you.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/getOrdersByDate?created=2012-4-5
```

But the problem looks interesting, because passing a `nil` to a where conditions should cause the following query:

```
SELECT "guest_orders".* FROM "guest_orders" WHERE "created_at" IS NULL
```

And in your case the whole SQL WHERE condition is missing.

#### Update #1

Seems like reloading needed.

To fetch the records for a date you could use the following method:

```
time = Time.zone.parse(params[:created])
range = time.beginning_of_day..time.end_of_day
@guest_orders = GuestOrder.where(:created_at => range)
```

#### Update #2

If you have a start and an end date:

```
t_start = Time.zone.parse(params[:start])
t_end = Time.zone.parse(params[:end])
range = t_start.beginning_of_day..t_end.end_of_day
@guest_orders = GuestOrder.where(:created_at => range)
```

Comment: KARASZI Istvan, I reloaded the application and removed the colon. Then I got this in server

Comment: Started GET "/api/getOrdersByDate?created=2012-3-22" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-06 14:02:48 +0530
  Processing by ApiController#getOrdersByDate as HTML
  Parameters: {"created"=>"2012-3-22"}
  SQL (0.7ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  GuestOrder Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "guest_orders".* FROM "guest_orders" WHERE "guest_orders"."created_at" = '2012-3-22'
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
  But in the browser I got nothing. only [] is appeared. But I have records in that date

Comment: when I use http://localhost:3000/api/getOrdersByDate?created=2012-03-22 it works properly But, while using http://localhost:3000/api/getOrdersByDate?created=2012-04-06          http://localhost:3000/api/getOrdersByDate?created=2012-04-06   It renders only [] empty Hash

Comment: Thanks KARASZI Istvan, It works well. But one problem, see the start and end time Parameters: {"created"=>"2012-04-07"}
  GuestOrder Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "guest_orders".* FROM "guest_orders" WHERE ("guest_orders"."created_at" BETWEEN '2012-04-06 18:30:00.000000' AND '2012-04-07 18:29:59.999999')
How can I change that, 5.30 hrs difference

Comment: You should parse with `Time.zone.parse` instead of `Time.parse` then.

Comment: Ya thanks, If I want to pick the records from_date to to_date, how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can get records by date using this query

```
    @results = GuestOrder.where("created_at = ? ", params[:created])
```

Try it

Comment: The original code in the OP does exactly the same: `GuestOrder.where(:created_at => (params[:created]))`